# What is the proper way to pass *args and **kwargs to a view?

Tags: django

Getting the error `Don't mix *args and **kwargs in call to reverse()!` when trying to pass args and kwargs to a view. I have tried many things at this point and can't get my head around this -- completely stuck on how to pass both to a view.

I need to pass both `unipart` and `newfile` to another view.

```
url(r'^(\d+)/(\d+)/convert/$', 'store.views.changetool', name = "convert"),
url(r'^(\d+)/view_part/$','store.views.view_part',name="view_part"),
```

VIEWS.PY (changetool)

```
def changetool (request, id, unipart=None):
    part = Part.objects.get(id=id)
    file = str (part.content)
    newfile = FormatConversion.ConvertToNew(file)
    return redirect('view_part', unipart, newfile = newfile)
```

VIEWS.PY (view_part)

```
def view_part(request, part_id, newfile = None):
```

Comment: Try `redirect('view_part', unipart, newfile)` it's telling you the problem in the error, either use args or kwargs, not both. (`redirect` includes an automatic call to `reverse`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have these imports:

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
```

and your `return` statement should be:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(
    reverse('path.to.function.view_part', args=(unipart, newfile))
)
```

Relevant docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls).

Comment: Thanks but in this case I get the error `NoReverseMatch`: `Reverse for 'store.views.view_part' with arguments '(u'54', u'file1.txt')' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.`

Comment: try: `reverse('path.to.function.view_part', kwargs={'unipart': unipart, 'newfile': newfile))`

Comment: @karthikr still getting the same message...I also did `'part_id': unipart`

Comment: @Ngenator I think you're looking at the wrong regex -- the one I'm passing to is the second one with `view_part` -- it is expecting one number and I want to pass a string also as a kwarg.

Comment: Ok any other hints? I'm so stumped :(

Comment: @user1328021 your parameters don't match the URL: you're passing `file1.txt` as the second argument, but the URLconf has `\d+` so is only expecting digits.

Comment: Thanks @DanielRoseman -- that is correct. My confusion is that by default I don't want that variable in the URL -- only is certain cases. I updated the URL to `url(r'^(\d+)/view_part/(\S+)$','store.views.view_part',name="view_part"),` ... this now works. However -- the default case is now broken because I'm not passing it the newfile string. I only pass it the digit from the URL. How can I account for both cases?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out -- just made two separate conditions in urls.py :-)

Comment: @user1328021 Yes you need 2 separate URLs in `urls.py`. Excuse me I was out, and I came in to see all these comments.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Well done for spotting that. I didn't spot that at first glance (I thought the problem was another).